# How can I inspect the links between DataBlocks as a graph?

Tags: mesh, objects, node-editor, linked-data

For instance, how can I inspect which object instances are linked to which mesh instances in a user interface similar to the *Node Editor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there was a feature like that up to 2.49, it was removed in blender 2.50 and has not been replaced.

While it hasn't been updated for a while [blender-aid](http://www.atmind.nl/?p=47) may be an option if it still works.

[image]